# How to pass data from widget component to another application component?

Tags: angular, angular-event-emitter

I have a widget, and I want to pass data to another angular componetnt?

in **widget.js**, I  have a component and I want to pass data.

```
import {Component,Output} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: "login",
  templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./login.component.scss"]
})
export class loginComponent implements OnInit {
  message: string = "Hello!";
  @Output() messageEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

//call this function on button click
 private loginUser(){
console.log("pass child message to parent");
    this.messageEvent.emit(this.message);
}

}
```

Login.html:

```
<!-- login page -->
<input type="button (click)="loginUser()">
```

in Angular Application, I am injecting widget.js

**in "Home" component**

```
<login (messageEvent)="receiveMessage($event)"></login>
```

**Home.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  message: string;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  receiveMessage($event) {
    console.log("event fired");
    this.message = $event;
  }
}
```

When I try above code only receiveMessage is not calling?

Comment: Please, show the login.html.

Comment: Make sure you're importing `EventEmitter` from angular/core in your loginComponent

Comment: Function loginUser it should not be public.

Comment: added login.html

Comment: @Freddy, Yes imported eventEmmiter also

Comment: any help????????